# Putting an image into nav bar div forces the text to stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css

The below code is what I have in my navbar, with the image the image goes to the top and the text goes to the bottom, is there anyway I can fix this? 
It works fine without the image

```
<div class="navbar">    
  <ul>
    <li><a class="select" href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/service.html">Service</a></li>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
    <li><a href="/sales.html">Sales</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/documents.html">Documents</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

it looks like this i.imgur.com/XQqX31X.png I would like it to look like this, if possible i.imgur.com/Te7lo4q.png

Comment: You should use <li><img src=""></li> since your attempt to use a element not supported by <ul> so either use li within the ul or add the image after the ul and use an absolute position to get the desired position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to be just another item in the list, then surround the `<img>` tag within an `<li>`. If you want it to display differently, then let us know and we'll help you achieve that.

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KQFRy/)

updated code:

```
<div class="navbar">    
  <ul>
    <li><a class="select" href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/service.html">Service</a></li>
      <li style="list-style:none"><img src="image.png" /></li>
    <li><a href="/sales.html">Sales</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/documents.html">Documents</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: That makes it look like this http://i.imgur.com/XQqX31X.png 
I would like it to look like this, if possible http://i.imgur.com/Te7lo4q.png

Comment: You will just need to update your CSS to achieve the desired result. Here's a start - http://jsfiddle.net/KQFRy/4/

Comment: Thanks for this, it work well! only thing is in internet explorer and firefox the image doesn't resize, only a small issue

Comment: Easy fixed, just update the following in the css - .list-img img{padding:0;margin:0;max-height:40px;} - view it here -> http://jsfiddle.net/KQFRy/5/

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` should be placed inside another `li` as an `img` is not a valid child of a `ul`.

Or perhaps it should come out of the list entirely and be placed before the `ul` not sure what your design is like but I think it'd make more sense to bring it out of that list entirely.